# Remotely remove all phone's data

Tags: applications, gmail, remote-control

I gave my phone away without removing the photos on it,now I know the gmail's account on that current phone.

Is there a way to remove all the data,or at least the photos on that phone,when I have the account running on it ? maybe install an app remotely ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just knowing the account name won't be enough (or one could simply iterate over all @gmail addresses to blank a lot of devices). But as you have that, there's one remote tool called "Email" you could use: write a mail to that account and ask to please remove the data you've left on the device.

Comment: That's an obvious sarcastic comment,look at the answer to know how to do it better next time.

Comment: Sorry if you feel like that, wadie – but it's fact. Once you've sold your device, and the new owner ***replaces*** your account by his/her own, just knowing the email address of the new account isn't enough. You didn't indicate you have the credentials for it – so I couldn't know you're talking about *your* account still being active on it. Thus knowing the Gmail address of the new owner was the much more likely assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to log in to the [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager).

You need to sign in with you google account (must be the same as on phone).
If your phone is still linked to your account and if it is connected to the internet you can fully remotely wipe your phone (= factory reset).

If the new owner has already changed the account, you have no chance to delete any data.